# How to add iptables rule to redirect http(s) traffic for specific service only (OpenVPN) and not affect another services (Apache2 etc)?

Tags: apache-http-server, openvpn, iptables, vps, squid

I have own VPS (Ubuntu 18). I have there runned `Apache2` and `OpenVPN` servers. Also I have there `Squid` proxy that I want to use with `OpenVPN` to intercept traffic and change headers like `user-agent`.

To manage iptables I use `firewall-cmd`.

I want to redirect **http(s) traffic** only for **OpenVPN** server and not affect **Apache2** traffic. How can I do this ? How can I add port forwarding rule for specific service only?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have some sort of website for OpenVPN management,
or using OpenVPN Access Server that has web management and wanted OpenVPN ti only captures VPN connection.

For OpenVPN, you can use the option by appending the 'port-share' in the server conf

`port-share 127.0.0.1 443` for the web port on 443

For OpenVPN Access Server

`/usr/local/openvpn_as/scripts/sacli -k vpn.server.port_share.enable -v true configput`

`/usr/local/openvpn_as/scripts/sacli -k vpn.server.port_share.ip_address -v 127.0.0.1 configput`

`/usr/local/openvpn_as/scripts/sacli -k vpn.server.port_share.port -v 443 configput`

`/usr/local/openvpn_as/scripts/sacli start`

This will make the OpenVPN capture the non-VPN traffic to 127.0.0.1:443 so squid can capture the rest of all through 443, I answered 443 because it works on all situations I mentioned above since I quite didn't understand the question in detail. Plus, no extra iptables needed on OpenVPN.

Thus, you can change the port to anything that you set on squid.